# Can´t connect Hyper-V manager to Hyper-V server

Tags: hyper-v

Trying to connect Hyper-V manager to our newly set up Hyper-V server and currently whenever I try, I get the error shown in the attached file. And just to clarify the server is out of the domain, whilst my PC is on the domain, also my PC is on Windows 10.

Things I have tried: Creating new profile outside of domain, turning off firewall on PC as well as on server.

[Image mentioned above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8M80.png)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make sure both your server and your client have their networks set to Private and that firewall rules on both networks are set to allow access. Also make sure you are using the credentials associated with the target server in the proper format, i.e. host-server\username and that VMM is running on the server. Make sure you're in the same domain. You'll have to either have both in a workgroup or both on the domain.